# aarch64 xtn2 clearing lower half

Tags: assembly, simd, arm64, neon, armv8

Is there an operation similar to `xtn2` but that actually clears the lower half instead of leaving it as is? I have a 128 bit vector `v0` whose view as `4s` is `{a,x,b,y}` with x and y irrelevant. I want to obtain `{0,0,a,b}`. If I do

```
xtn2     v0.4s, v0.2d
mov      v0.d[0], xzr
```

I get the result I want. Is there a way to do this with one instruction or in a more efficient way?

Comment: If you can spare another register, then `movi v1.4s, #0 ; xtn2 v1.4s, v0.2d` may be a little better, since the `movi` could execute out-of-order much earlier, without waiting for the input in `v0` to be ready.  Also, I believe moves from general-purpose to SIMD registers are quite slow, though I don't know if this applies to the zero register.

Comment: I suppose you've already considered whether you could rewrite the subsequent code to work with `{a, b, 0, 0}` instead, and then just use `xtn`?

Comment: Thanks, I haven't given up on an `xtn`-based approach, it may be possible, but it may require a significant refactor

Comment: Perhaps `uzp2` can be used for this.

Comment: @fuz: Good spot.  I think it's actually `uzp1 v0.4s, v1.4s, v0.4s` where `v1` is filled with zeros.  That seems like the best answer yet - you still need a spare register, but it can stay zero throughout, e.g. across loop iterations.

Comment: why is `uzp1` + zeroing a register better than `xtn2` + zeroing a register?

Comment: @potuz: With `uzp1` you never have to write to the second register after initially zeroing it.  If you're doing this in a loop you can `movi v1.4s, #0` before the loop, and each iteration is only `uzp1 v0.4s, v1.4s, v0.4s`.  With `xtn2`, you overwrite the register that was previously zeroed, so you need a `movi v1.4s, #0` on every loop iteration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Credit to fuz for the original suggestion)

If you can spare another register to hold zero, say `v1`, then you can do

```
uzp1 v0.4s, v1.4s, v0.4s
```

In general `uzp1 vd.t, vn.t, vm.t` packs the even-numbered elements (zero-based) of `vn` into the low half of `vd`, and the even elements of `vm` into the high half.  (`uzp2` does the same for the odd elements.)  So if `v1` is zero, then you get zeros in the low half of the result, and the 0th and 2nd elements of `v0` in the high half, which are your `a` and `b`.

Note that if you're doing this many times, then `v1` can be initialized to zero once and used throughout your code, since it is not written by this instruction.  (It would be easier if ARM had supplied a zero SIMD register `vzr`.)   If we neglect the overhead of that, then this is pretty efficient.  Looking at Cortex A-72 timings for instance (because I happen to have its Optimization Guide handy), `uzp1` is the cheapest kind of SIMD instruction, 3 cycles latency and throughput of 2 per cycle (it can execute in either of the two SIMD arithmetic pipelines).

One performance note on your original version is that moving between SIMD and general-purpose registers is very expensive and should be avoided whenever possible.  On Cortex A-72, `mov v*, x*` (special-case alias of `ins`) is 8 cycles latency and throughput of 1 per cycle, and it needs both the load pipeline (of which there is just one) as well as one of the two SIMD arithmetic pipelines.  Conceivably there could be a special case for `xzr`, but no mention of one for Cortex A-72.

Unfortunately there's not a direct alternative for zeroing one element in a SIMD register, as far as I know; `movi` writes an immediate to all the elements, not just some of them.  So even if you were sticking with `xtn2`, you might want to keep zero in another register because `ins v0.d[0], v1.d[0]` is cheap.